# YII2 error - The “id” configuration for the Application is required

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

When I am running the unit test case in yii2 advanced php framework from frontend\tests\unit\models\ContactFormTest.php I am getting some errors as below

**This is my ContactFormTest.php**

```
 namespace frontend\tests\unit\models;

 use Yii;
 use frontend\models\ContactForm;

class ContactFormTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{

   public function testSendEmail()
   {
    $model = new ContactForm();

    $model->attributes = [
        'name' => 'vinayak',
        'email' => 'vinayak.tanksali@effone.com',
        'subject' => 'very important letter subject',
        'body' => 'hi',
    ];

    expect_that($model->sendEmail('vinayak.tanksali@effone.com'));

    // using Yii2 module actions to check email was sent
    $this->tester->seeEmailIsSent();

    $emailMessage = $this->tester->grabLastSentEmail();
    expect('valid email is sent', $emailMessage)->isInstanceOf('yii\mail\MessageInterface');
    expect($emailMessage->getTo())->hasKey('admin@example.com');
    expect($emailMessage->getFrom())->hasKey('tester@example.com');
    expect($emailMessage->getSubject())->equals('very important letter subject');
     expect($emailMessage->toString())->contains('body of current    message');
        }
  }
```

**First Error**

[yii\base\InvalidConfigException] The "id" configuration for the Application is required.

1  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php:220

2  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php:202

3  yii\base\Application->__construct

4  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php:383

5  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php:156

6  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php:349

7  Codeception\Subscriber\Module->before

8  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:212

9  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:44

**Second Error**

[yii\base\InvalidConfigException] Unknown component ID: i18n

1  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php:139

2  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php:742

3  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php:580

4  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php:526

5  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\validators\RequiredValidator.php:60

6  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\BaseObject.php:109

7  yii\base\BaseObject->__construct

8  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php:383

9  C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php:156

10 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2_test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php:349

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 2.

**Can any one please help me out on this thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

Try to add id in you config file (i.e. main.php) , like below:

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
   'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    :::::::::::::
]
```

ID param is required in yii2. You will need to setup in your Frontend (i.e.  frontend/config/main.php)